# Is this good Database Normalization?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-normalization, join

I am a beginner at using mysql and I am trying to learn the best practices. I have setup a similar structure as seen below.

(main table that contains all unique entries) **TABLE = 'main_content'**

```
+------------+---------------+------------------------------+-----------+
| content_id |  (deleted)    | title                        | member_id | 
+------------+---------------+------------------------------+-----------+
|          6 |               | This is a very spe?cal t|_st |      1    |
+------------+---------------+------------------------------+-----------+
```

(Provides the total of each difficulty and joins id --> actual name) **TABLE = 'difficulty'**

```
+---------------+-------------------+------------------+
| difficulty_id | difficulty_name   | difficulty_total |
+---------------+-------------------+------------------+
|             1 | Absolute Beginner |                1 |
|             2 | Beginner          |                1 | 
|             3 | Intermediate      |                0 |
|             4 | Advanced          |                0 |
|             5 | Expert            |                0 |
+---------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

(This table ensures that multiple values can be inserted for each entry. For example, 
       this specific entry indicates that there are 2 difficulties associated with the submission)
**TABLE = 'lookup_difficulty'**

```
+------------+---------------+
| content_id | difficulty_id |
+------------+---------------+  
|          6 |             1 |
|          6 |             2 |
+------------+---------------+
```

I am joining all of this into a readable query:

```
SELECT group_concat(difficulty.difficulty_name) as difficulty, member.member_name
FROM main_content
INNER JOIN difficulty ON difficulty.difficulty_id 
IN (SELECT difficulty_id FROM main_content, lookup_difficulty WHERE lookup_difficulty.content_id = main_content.content_id )
INNER JOIN member ON member.member_id = main_content.member_id
```

The above works fine, but I am wondering if this is good practice. I practically followed the structure laid out [Wikipedia's Database Normalization example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Example).

When I run the above query using `EXPLAIN`, it says: 'Using where; Using join buffer' and also that I am using 2 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY (s) . I don't see any way to NOT use sub-queries to achieve the same affect, but then again I'm a noob so perhaps there is a better way....

Comment: Why does `main_contant` has a FK to difficulty AND a lookup table? Could you explain what you are trying to build, so we can evaluate your design?

Comment: Looks to me like you can scrap the lookup_difficulty table, and instead just use a composite PK in main_content on (content_id,difficulty_id)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to delete that column. I am not using difficulty_id.. I will edit the post. I am trying to relate all tables essentially the main_content.content_id.

Comment: @Justin to evaluate your design, we need to know what you are trying to model. For example a blog post with comments, etc. If we don't know that, we can't say if your design is valid for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @cularis I am trying to create a website where users can add content (tutorials, guides, news items, etc). Every post will go into the 'main_content' table. From there, most of the entries will be identified by the above scheme where the 'content_id' links to their posted attributes such as difficulty, applications, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `lookup_difficulty` provides a link between `content` and `difficulty` I would suggest you take out the `difficulty_id` column from your `main_content` table. Since you can have multiple lookups for each `content_id`, you would need some extra business logic to determine which `difficulty_id` to put in your `main_content` table (or multiple entries in the `main_content` table for each `difficulty_id`, but that goes against normalization practices). For ex. the biggest value / smallest value / random value. In either case, it does not make much sense.

Other than that the table looks fine.

---

**Update**

Saw you updated the table :)

Just as a side-note. Using `IN` can slow down your query (`IN` can cause a table-scan). In any case, it used to be that way, but I'm sure that these days the SQL compiler optimizes it pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for the help! As a side note, where can I find out typical speeds that mysql uses? In other words, how did you find out that `IN` is slow? I can achieve the same result if I substitute `IN` with: `= ANY` . I don't know which is faster and `EXPLAIN` does not provide much insight.

Comment: @Justin - Mostly from experience and reading. There are proprietary software that can analyze your MySQL queries, not any good open-source / free ones that I know of (anyone please feel free to give examples).

Comment: I guess I could always use the profiler. I will be using a lot of joins for retrieval of each submitted content, so I better make sure its optimized to some degree.

Comment: If you have a profiler that works nice, awesome! Have a look at the query @Tudor Constantin gave. Inner joins can typically speeds up your query execution as each join decreases the scope of the search.

Comment: One last question, what fields should be used for indexing? Currently, all columns with an `_id` are indexes, but I'm not sure if a clustered index for the `look_up` tables would do better.

Answer (score 2):

The DB design looks fine - regarding your query, you could rewrite it exclusively with joins like:

```
SELECT group_concat(difficulty.difficulty_name) as difficulty, member.member_name
      FROM main_content
        INNER JOIN lookup_difficulty ON main_content.id = lookup_difficulty.content_id
        INNER JOIN difficulty ON difficulty.id = lookup_difficulty.difficulty_id
        INNER JOIN member ON member.member_id = main_content.member_id
```

Comment: Excellent! Works fine when `ON difficulty.difficulty_id`  is substituted for `ON difficulty.id`. Thank YOU!!   After using 'EXPLAIN', all `SELECT_TYPES` are `SIMPLE` and no subqueries. This is exacty what I was looking for!